# Pandas: Trouble Setting a Slice to a Value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use boolean indexing to set the rows with a `Title` not in `["Mr", "Miss", "Mrs", "Master"]` to `Rare`.  Here's my attempt:

```
combined_df[(~combined_df.Title.isin(["Mr", "Miss", "Mrs", "Master"]))].Title = "Rare"
```

When I do `pd.value_counts(combined_df.Title)`, I get:

```
Mr              757
Miss            260
Mrs             197
Master           61
Dr                8
Rev               8
Col               4
Major             2
Mlle              2
Ms                2
Jonkheer          1
the Countess      1
Capt              1
Dona              1
Don               1
Lady              1
Mme               1
Sir               1
Name: Title, dtype: int64
```

So the attempted changes don't take hold.

Any idea why / how to fix this?

Comment: `combined_df.loc[~combined_df.Title.isin(["Mr", "Miss", "Mrs", "Master"]), 'Title'] = 'Rare'`

Comment: Are you sure this is done inplace?

Comment: You can use the below code:

    `value = df['Title'].isin(['Mr','Mrs','Miss','Master'])
    column_name = 'B'
    df.loc[value, column_name] = "Rare"`